# Как вернуть старую цветовую гамму Входящих?

Tags: поддержка, дизайн, уведомления

Входящие превратились в серое унылое.
Как вернуть старые цвета, где сразу видно что заголовок, а что собственно сообщение?

Comment: Я думаю, оно ещё будет эволюционировать и это просто некий промежуточный вариант. Обо всех замечаниях и предложениях стоит писать в графе ответов под [вопросом](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/384148/339911) на MSE.

Comment: а, ну все понятно, в очередной раз выкатили сырое тесто вместо нормального продукта

Comment: Надо ж как-то тестировать :)

Comment: У непрочитанных уведомлений цвета старые. А про прочитанные наверно подразумевается, что читать их второй раз уже нет смысла)

Comment: Stylish и подобные расширения  в помощь)) Они всегда помогут сделать UI таким, каким нравится именно вам))  (у меня стоИт расширение, я себе всё сделал как мне удобно)

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Я бы вместо Stylish выбрал бы всё-таки Stylus, он как-никак сВоБоДнЫй и поддерживается сообществом, а Stylish проприетарный, соответственно никакой поддержки от сообщества ждать не стоит :)

Comment: @ΝNL993 без разницы. Смысл всё равно в другом. Да и на примитивном уровне написания стилей вполне. Нужды в том, чтобы оно ещё супы варило и бельё стирало - не требуется